# How can a class that implements multiple interfaces be referenced by either interface within Doctrine?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

[image]

- Class `A` implements `Foo` and `Bar`.
- Class `P` references a collection of `Foo`s.
- Class `Q` references a collection of `Bar`s.

How can class `A` be referred to as a `Foo` by `P` and a `Bar` by `Q` using Doctrine association mapping annotations?

Problems:

- Interfaces and traits cannot be the target of entity relationships: only abstract or concrete classes are treated as entities by Doctrine.
- We cannot convert both interfaces to abstract classes because PHP does not support multiple inheritance.
- The interfaces cannot be merged into one because other classes (not shown) may implement only one of the interfaces.

Comment: Did you have a look into the [ResolveTargetEntityListener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html)? This allows you to reference the targetEntity of your association to a interface.

Comment: @BramGerritsen You can target interfaces with that but it appears that the entity resolver can only be configured to resolve each interface to just one hard-coded concrete implementation. That cannot help because I need to store many concrete implementations. Without a discriminator column in the database surely it is impossible to tell which concrete instance a data row represents?